# Can't return varchar value from stored procedure in asp.net

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I am trying to return a varchar from stored procedure with the **following code:**

```
Dim uname As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("userName", uconnect)
uname.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
Dim outVal As SqlParameter = uname.Parameters.Add("userName", SqlDbType.VarChar)
uname.Parameters.AddWithValue("userID", userLog)
uname.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", " ")
outVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
uname.ExecuteReader() 'This line trows exception saying: 
' "String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0."

uconnect.Close()
Dim name As String = outVal.Value
```

**Here is SP code:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[userName] 
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @userID int,
 @userName varchar(30) OUTPUT
AS
   SELECT @userName = owner FROM users WHERE user_id = @userID
```

I also tryied setting the size of the returned varchar parameter like this:

uname.Parameters.Add("userName", SqlDbType.VarChar, **30**)

but if I add size parameter to the line above, when I run a program it trows a new exception saying: "Stored Procedure UserName has too many arguments specified".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SqlParameter.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x.aspx) has a number of overloads, but the one you need to use in this situation is the form you tried with the column size:

```
uname.Parameters.Add("userName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30)
```

The error you're getting is because you've declared the userName parameter twice - once as userName, and again as @userName - this causes three parameters to be sent to Sql Server, when your stored procedure only accepts two.  Remove this line and all will be well:

```
' Remove this line
uname.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is really that simple, then it's probably easier to just select the result and execute scalar.

```
Dim uname As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("userName", uconnect)
uname.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
uname.Parameters.AddWithValue("userID", userLog)

Dim name As String
name = uname.ExecuteScalar()
uconnect.Close()
```

With the sproc like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[userName] 
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @userID int,
AS
   SELECT owner FROM users WHERE user_id = @userID
```

Note: I'm a c# programmer, so sorry if this isn't perfect.

Comment: What is the differece between exectuteScalar and executeReader?